# Syntax for Swift 3 AddConstraintWithFormat?

Tags: ios, swift

I found sourcode:

```
view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(50)]", views: menuBar)
```

And I'm using **Swift 3**, it's not working in my Xcode 8

Can someone tell me what code for that ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

You should write a function like this:

```
   func addContraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewDict = [String: UIView]()

        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewDict[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    }
```

It would work for you!

May be you need [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html) to use this function.

Answer (score 4):

You have to write extension for UIView. Something like that:

```
extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 Implementation of the same constraints, just in case someone wants to use the new format instead of extending UIView:

```
private func setupConstraints(){

    //topView is a simple UIView with a red background for example purposes
    view.addSubview(topView)
    topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let cn1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    //Menu bar trailing end is 20 px from right edge of the screen
    let cn2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    //Menu bar height = constant 60
    let cn3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)
    //Menu bar width greater than or equal to 400
    let cn4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 400)
    //Menu bar vertical padding from the top edge of the screen = 20
    let cn5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)

    view.addConstraint(cn1)
    view.addConstraint(cn2)
    view.addConstraint(cn3)
    view.addConstraint(cn4)
    view.addConstraint(cn5)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code

```
let tempView = UIView()
tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(tempView)

let views = ["view": view, "tempView": tempView]
let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view]-(<=0)-[tempView(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)

view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
```

Let me know if this help you or not.